# If $(f,g)$ is measurable than $f$ and $g$ are measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f : (Z,z) \rightarrow (X,x)$ and $g : (Z,z) \rightarrow (Y,y)$. If $(f,g)=(Z,z) \rightarrow (XxY, x⊗y)$ are measurable then $f$ and $g$ are measurable? If so how can I show that?
My approach to this question is to take a measurable set $B \times C$ in $x⊗y$ and than consider inverse and so on... But I can't have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$
z\ni(f,g)^{-1}(B\times C)=f^{-1}(B)\cap g^{-1}(C)
$$
for all $B\in x$ and $C\in y$. To show that, say, $f$ is measurable, you simply choose $C$ wisely.